# html tag is showing in browser literally

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

```
<div id="list_content" readonly="readonly" style="resize: none;"><%= lists.content %></div>
```

This is my html code and getting lists variable from node.js server. If the content in database is `<p>This is test</p>` it's not parsing the HTML, and showing `<p>This is test</p>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass html to ejs use `<%- lists.content %>` instead of `<= lists.content %>`

To learn move about the different types of EJS tags look here: http://ejs.co/

Answer (score 2):

In html `'` is a special chacacter. You should htmlencode your html before showing it.

You can use the following htmlencode function:

```
function htmlEncode(string) {
    return string.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
        .replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
```

Use it like this:

```
<%= htmlEcode(lists.content) %>
```